# Como posso escrever um loop para calcular cada valor de uma lista que não seja pré-definida

Tags: python, python-3.x, loop

Olá, sou iniciante na programação e nesse fórum tb ^^"
estou tendo dificuldade para calcular o desvio padrão de uma lista de valores ( não um lista pré-definida, ela é feita através de um input)
Como eu posso criar um loop para pegar os valores armazenados na lista ?

tentei utilizar o for e não deu certo, aparentemente ele estava pegando o indice em vez dos valores.
o que eu quero saber é:
Tem como fazer um loop para q eu possa pegar um valor da lista subtrair ele de uma media, salvar o valor e somar com o próximo valor da lista ?

el = ((listaVal[0] - medialis) ** 2) + ((listaVal[1] - medialis) ** 2) + ((listaVal[2] - medialis) ** 2) + (
(listaVal[3] - medialis) ** 2) + ((listaVal[4] - medialis) ** 2)

Eu estava fazendo desse jeito, porém só funciona para uma lista com 5 elementos nem mais nem menos

Comment: Quais serão os  tipos de valores que desejas inserir nesta lista? inteiros ou reais?

Comment: provavelmente inteiros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolver esta questão você pode utilizar o seguinte algoritmo:

```
import numpy as np

m = int(input('Digite o número de linhas: '))
n = int(input('Digite o número de colunas: '))

lista = list()
for i in range(1, m + 1):
    linha = list()
    for j in range(1, n + 1):
        while True:
            try:
                v = int(input(f'Digite o {j}º valor da {i}ª linha: '))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas valores inteiros!\033[m')
        linha.append(v)
    lista.append(linha)

d_p = np.std(lista)
print(f'\033[32mO desvio padrão é:\n{d_p:.2f}\033[m')
```

Observe que, mesmo inserindo valores inteiros, o resultado do desvio padrão sempre será um número de ponto flutuante.

[Veja aqui](https://www.todamateria.com.br/desvio-padrao/) a definição de desvio padrão.

Observe que, neste algoritmo importei a biblioteca numpy, que obrigatoriamente já havia instalado na minha IDE.

Quando executamos este algoritmo nos é solicitado o número de linhas e colunas.

**Por que isso?**

Porque com o número de linha e de colunas posso montar uma estrutura de uma matriz, mais precisamente uma lista de listas.

Observe também que o aninhamento de blocos `for` monta uma lista de listas contendo todos os valores que serão passados.

Posteriormente o método `std` da biblioteca `numpy` calcula o desvio padrão de todos os valores de todas as listas.

Agora, se você deseja apenas calcular a **soma** de todos os desvios padrões das listas, você pode utilizar o seguinte algoritmo:

```
import numpy as np

n = int(input('Quantas lista desejas calcular? '))

soma = 0
for c in range(1, n + 1):
    lista = list(map(int, input(f'Digite todos os valores da {c}º lista: ').split()))
    d_p = np.std(lista)
    soma += d_p

print(f'\033[32mA soma dos desvios padrões são: {soma:.2f}\033[m')
```

Observe que quando executamos este segundo algoritmo recebemos a seguinte mensagem:`Quantas listas desejas calcular`. Neste momento devemos informar a quantidade de listas. Em seguida, recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite todos os valores da 1ª lista`. Neste momento devemos digitar **todos** os valores na **mesma** linha, **separados** por um só espaço e, em seguida, pressionar enter.

Posteriormente devemos digitar os valores das demais listas.

Para cada lista o algoritmo irá calcular o seu `desvio padrão` e acumulará os seus valores na variável contadora `soma`. em seguida será exibido o valor.